# Regular expression in Python to exclude the last 3 words of a string?

Tags: regex

#### My problem

- I have a string made by at least 4 words separated by spaces (it is the output of a particular execution of the command **nmcli** on Linux);
- between every words could be present more than one space.

I need to write a Python function able to get the start of the string excluding the last three words.
So for example:

```
1) input_string = "word1    word2 word3      word4"
                   -----
                     |--> function returns 'word1'

2) input_string = "word1 word2 word3      word4 word5"
                   -----------
                        |--> function returns 'word1 word2' (with only a space between word1 and word2)

3) input_string = "word1    word2 word3      word4 word5"
                   --------------
                          |--> function returns 'word1    word2' (with 3 spaces between word1 and word2 as in the input_string)
```

#### My code not always work

I have tried with the following code:

```
def func(input_string):
    input_string = " ".join(input_string.split())
    l = len(input_string)
    start_string = input_string[0]
    if l > 4:
       i = 1
       start_string += ' '
       while i < l - 3:
           start_string += input_string[i]
           i += 1
           if i == l - 3:
               break
           else:
               start_string += ' '
    return start_string
```

My code works for the examples 1 and 2 but it doesn't work for example 3 where are present 3 spaces between `word1` and `word2`. In this case my function returns `"word1 word2"` with only one space between `word1` and `word2`.

#### Question

I think that this problem could be easily solved by regular expression, but I don't know anything about regular expressions.
Could someone give me a suited regular expression to reach my goal?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `split()` to split the string into words, then slice that to remove the last 3 words?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but what about the example 3?

Comment: I must have misread, I thought you wanted one space between each word in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp to match the last 3 words.

```
import re

def func(input_string):
    return re.sub(r'(?:\s+\w+){3}$', '', input_string)

print(func("word1    word2 word3      word4"))
print(func("word1 word2 word3      word4 word5"))
print(func("word1    word2 word3      word4 word5"))
```

`\s+` matches a sequence of whitespace, `\w+` matches a sequence of alphanumeric characters. `{3}` matches 3 of these groups, and `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: It can not behave properly in some cases: 
input_string = "word1    word2 word3?      word4" 
print(func(input_string)) 

Will return "word1    word2 word3?      word4"

Comment: I assumed words can only have alphanumeric characters. `?` is not alphanumeric.

Comment: The question says words are separated by spaces, it doesn't say anything about other punctuation.

Comment: If words are supposed to be anything except spaces, use `\S` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `re.split()` and slicing.

```
import re

input_string = "word1    word2 word3      word4 word5"
print(re.split(r'\s+',input_string)[:3])
```

Comment: He might want to keep the number of spaces between the words

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex.
You can extract all words then create a regex with the last n words and any number of spaces before, between and after them then get the string before the regex result

```
import re


def exclude_last_n_words(input_string, n=3):
    words = input_string.split()
    if len(words) <= n:
        return ''
    last_n_words = words[-n:]

    # Create a regex pattern for the last n words, allowing any number of spaces between them
    pattern = r'\s*'.join(re.escape(word) for word in last_n_words) + r'\s*$'

    # Find and remove the last n words
    match = re.search(pattern, input_string)
    if match:
        return input_string[:match.start()]
    else:
        return ''

input_string1 = "word1    word2 word3      word4"
input_string2 = "word1 word2 word3      word4 word5"
input_string3 = "word1    word2 word3      word4 word5"

print(exclude_last_n_words(input_string1))
print(exclude_last_n_words(input_string2))
print(exclude_last_n_words(input_string3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be using `(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)$` like

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)$')
print(pattern.search(words).groups())
```